# How to give extensionless files an extension in SubFolders

Tags: powershell, file-extension

I have a parent folder with 100s of subfolders. In those there are random files that do not have any extension applied to them.

I'm trying to use PS to apply a .txt extension to any file found that just doesn't have an extension.

Things I've attempted:

```
Get-ChildItem G:\Those -Filter {!($_.Extension)} -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.DirectoryName + '.txt'}

Get-ChildItem G:\Those (gci -File -Recurse | ?{!($_.Extension)}) |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '.txt'}
```

This one works if I have a file extension but I don't know how to convert it to only find files without an extension.

```
Get-ChildItem G:\Those -Filter *.ext -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '.txt'}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or
device name.
At line:1 char:63
+ ... {-not $_.Extension} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.DirectoryName+'.txt'}
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: I think I got farther. I think this is giving me the correct output but now I'm stuck on how to get the rename to work.

Comment: Get-ChildItem G:\Those -Recurse | where {-not $_.Extension} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.DirectoryName+'.txt'}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in a roundabout way, but if someone could provide a one-liner for this I would love you.

`{-not $_.Extension}` got me those files but the rename wouldn't work until I changed `$_.DirectoryName+` to `$_.FileName+` with the `-File` added before `-Recurse`.

This actually renamed the files that had no extension to just ".txt"

Name that they all had the same name I used my original command to rename anything `.txt` to `$_.DirectoryName+'.txt'`,  which did the trick.